# Howto open files with "shell:windows" syntax

Tags: windows, shell

Entering `shell:windows\win.ini` into "run box" or explorer address box leads to a message box `Windows cannot find 'shell:windows\win.ini'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.`

Though the file is there.

Same with an exe file `shell:windows\notepad.exe`:  `Windows can't find 'shell:windows\notepad.exe'. Check the spelling and try again.`

It works fine, if the location is a folder `shell:windows\System32\`.

Opening (or starting) files works if you use the equivalent environment variable.

- `%windir%\win.ini`
- `%windir%\notepad.exe`

Both (shell:windows and %windir%) point to `C:\Windows`.

How can i make the "shell:*" syntax work for files?
Is there something "special" about the "shell:*" syntax, which allows only opening Folders, but prohibits opening files?

Comment: Those are URIs. They don’t (directly) resolve to paths.

Comment: So that it works for opening subfolders is just a lucky coincidence?

Comment: Shell commands should be used to navigate to folders in windows and help to retrieve resources quickly instead of executing an app or opening a file.

Answer (score 0):

Shell commands should be used to navigate to folders in windows and help to retrieve resources quickly instead of executing an app or opening a file.

%windir%\notepad.exe is a path can be executed, while shell:windows\notepad.exe is not a executable command.

[Shell Commands for Windows 10: Navigating Common Folders in Windows](https://www.mirazon.com/shell-commands-for-windows-10-navigating-common-folders-in-windows/)